# Arquillian, Runclient test as remote

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss, jboss-arquillian

I wonder how to launch Arquillian rest client test as jboss remote profile.

This is my test class:

```
@RunAsClient
@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public class MemberRegistrationClientTest {

    @Deployment
    public static Archive<?> createTestArchive() {
        return ShrinkWrap.create(WebArchive.class, "test.war").addPackage(Member.class.getPackage())
                .addClasses(Resources.class, MemberResourceRESTService.class, MemberRepository.class, JaxRsActivator.class)
                //.addAsResource("META-INF/test-persistence.xml", "META-INF/persistence.xml")
                .addAsResource("import.sql")
                .addAsWebInfResource(EmptyAsset.INSTANCE, "beans.xml");

    }

    final String RESOURCE_PREFIX = "rest";

    @ArquillianResource
    URL deploymentUrl;

    @Test
    public void testGetCustomerByIdUsingClientRequest() throws Exception {
        //deploymentUrl = new URL("http://localhost:8180/test/");
        // GET http://localhost:8080/test/rest/customer/1
        System.out.println("deployementUrl: " + deploymentUrl.toString() +  RESOURCE_PREFIX + "/members/0");

        ClientRequest request = new ClientRequest(deploymentUrl.toString() + RESOURCE_PREFIX + "/members/0");
        request.header("Accept", MediaType.APPLICATION_XML);

        // we're expecting a String back
        ClientResponse<String> responseObj = request.get(String.class);

        Assert.assertEquals(200, responseObj.getStatus());
        System.out.println("GET /members/0 HTTP/1.1\n\n" + responseObj.getEntity());


    }

}
```

First off I launch my Jboss with application already installer, then I launch test with:

```
mvn clean test -Parq-jbossas-remote.
```

The issue is the deployment url is wrong because it points to localhost:8080/test, while the correct URL should be localhost:8080/myproject.

Is there any simple way to set the context root where the package should point ?

Comment: What's the reason you think it should be `myproject` for the context name? From the deployment it looks like it should be `test`.

Comment: yes but regardless the name it is possible to set up the context root. So far I see 2 solutions: 

    1 - Add a web.xml on test/resources with context-root = myproject

    2 - Change the deployment url within the test method itself

Answer (score 0):

If you want the deployment context to be `myproject` the simplest option is to name the test deployment `myproject.war`. You can do that by changing `ShrinkWrap.create(WebArchive.class, "test.war")` to `ShrinkWrap.create(WebArchive.class, "myproject.war")`.

The other option would be to add a `jboss-web.xml`.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<jboss-web>
   <context-root>/myproject</context-root>
</jboss-web>
```

Comment: Both two options would fail because can't deploy on the same server two project of the same name/context root (that's because I'm launching with remote option)

Comment: Right you can only have one deployment context name. That means your tests would have to use the `test` context. It's the only way.